# Compile a list of unused resources in .NET website project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, replace, web

I am working on a cleanup of a large website with a bunch of abandoned resources - multiple copies of the same page, images, archive folders etc.

If the folder or a document is not referenced anywhere in the current project, I want it to be on a list, so I can review and delete it.

My current process is to open a Web Site project in VS 2010, then run "Find and Replace", then review/delete resource if not used.

Any ideas on how to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove unused references and strings you could follow the below steps in visual studio 2010 .

Removing unused strings : right click the code and remove the unused strings as below

[image]

Removing unused references as below :

[image]

Also you can use **[Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)**.

> If the folder or a document is not referenced anywhere in the current
>   project, I want it to be on a list, so I can review and delete it.

In this case you can use **[FindUnusedFiles](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28650fe9-f41e-4db9-9d61-4e3f59c85b5e)** :

Find Unused Files .
Find and eliminate unused images & files in web projects/applications.

This extension helps you parse a website solution or project to find and eliminate unused images or other orphaned file types that are not being referenced in your sourcecode anymore.

Files can actually be of any type, but will most likely be images that you wish to remove from a website you are working on.

Works as a Standalone Application, from the Windows Explorer context menu, from the Command Line, or as a Visual Studio extension. Thank's to the command line it can easily be integrated with your favorite development IDE too.